# Firebase Storage Exception when fetching downloadUrl [Flutter]

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage

When trying to use FireBase Cloud Storage to get a video downloadUrl

```
final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
downloadUrl() async {
  final downloadUrl =
      await storage.ref("User_uploadVideo/videoplayback.mp4").getDownloadURL();
  return downloadUrl;
}
```

An exception is thrown saying `Exception: [firebase_storage/unauthenticated] User is unauthenticated. Authenticate and try again.`

Even tho I have opened the security rules to public for development.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the online Storage rules. In case you changed the rules locally, did you deploy them?

Comment: im not even sure how to change the rules locally, but I showed the rules that are saved in firebase

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  ); 
...
```

Also, make sure to have AppCheck disabled.

Comment: The error still continues

Comment: @JoeCodes Do you have activated Firebase in your code like this: `void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  ); ...`

Comment: I have it initialized but I don't have the `options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,` and when I try and add it flutter doesn't recognize it